# Removing item from cart deleted cardelivergroupmethod from database?

Tags: b2b-commerce, lwr

I have an issue with an LWR b2b commerce store where the shipping integration is not being triggered when I remove an item from my cart and then reenter the checkout page.

I need the shipping integration to be computed every time i enter the checkout page, as the shipping cost will change based on the products that are in the cart.

For some reason is the cardelivergroupmethod being deleted, or i linked to the cart when i remove an item, which i assume is a standard process by salesforce.

How does salesforce determine that the integration does not need to run - and the prior execution is ok?

How do i handle this?